# Encoding a PDF to Base64 in Java, decoding in PL/SQL: doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, plsql, base64, oracle-apex

So, I'm working on a web services project.

Basically, it boils down to:

1. PL/SQL side uploads a PDF file, then Base64-encodes this file, then sends it to my REST webservice.
2. Java webservice receives the file. I save this file before doing anything else (just for a test): as expected, the file is corrupt (it's a Base64-string, this is normal).
3. Java webservice Base64-decodes the file and then proceeds to do whatever it needs to do with the file. I save the file once again after this decoding, and once again it works as expected and I'm able to open and read the PDF.
4. PL/SQL now requests to re-download the file. I re-encode the file and send it back to the requestor. I save the file after encoding, and as expected (it's Base64 encoded again): it doesn't work (corrupt).
5. PL/SQL receives the file, Base64-decodes the file and tries to open it... Bam, corrupt, unable to read the file.

Probably something is wrong between the communication: it's Base64-encoded in Java, Base64-decoded in PL/SQL. You'd suspect there'd be no difference as it's using a standard (I guess Base64 is standard, right?).

We tried both options: after I re-encode the PDF in Java, I try to once again re-decode it and save it; this file is correct and I'm able to read the PDF. So we'd suppose the encoding in Java is correct. We also tried this in PL/SQL - upload a BLOB, encode to Base64, decode it back, download and open. This also works. So we'd suppose the encoding and decoding part in PL/SQL works, too.

What is weird is that I can Base64 encode the file in PL/SQL, then decode it in Java, then save and read it. It only goes wrong when I re-encode the file in Java and try to decode it in PL/SQL. So that sounds to me like there can't really be a problem between standards used in PL/SQL - Java, because then the first step would fail too.

We're using the commons library in Java (`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`). In PL/SQL, we've tried using the UTL-packages as well as a custom method as well as a Java stored procedure as well as the Apex_webservice (`apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(p_blob)` and `apex_web_service.clobbase642blob(p_clob)`). They all give the same result.

We're slowly running out of ideas. Is there anyone who has another, better idea?

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

This is how the file is decoded in PL/SQL:

```
FUNCTION encode_base64 (p_blob_in IN BLOB) 
    RETURN CLOB IS
        v_clob             CLOB;
        v_result           CLOB;
        v_offset           INTEGER;
        v_chunk_size       BINARY_INTEGER := (48 / 4) * 3;
        v_buffer_varchar   VARCHAR2 (48);
        v_buffer_raw       RAW (48);
    BEGIN
        IF p_blob_in IS NULL THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (v_clob, TRUE);
        v_offset := 1;
        FOR i IN 1 .. CEIL (DBMS_LOB.getlength (p_blob_in) / v_chunk_size) LOOP
            DBMS_LOB.read (p_blob_in, v_chunk_size, v_offset, v_buffer_raw);
            v_buffer_raw := UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (v_buffer_raw);
            v_buffer_varchar := UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2 (v_buffer_raw);
            DBMS_LOB.writeappend (v_clob, LENGTH (v_buffer_varchar), v_buffer_varchar);
            v_offset := v_offset + v_chunk_size;
        END LOOP;
        v_result := v_clob;
        DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (v_clob);
        RETURN v_result;
END encode_base64;
```

This is how the file is encoded in Java:

```
byte[] content = /*Here is my content in bytes. Before encoding, when I save, this is correct*/
Base64.encodeBase64String(content);
```

--- EDIT 2 ---

I accidently added the decode part in PL/SQL above. Here's the encode part in PL/SQL.

```
function decode_base64(p_clob_in in clob) return blob is
    v_blob blob;
    v_result blob;
    v_offset integer;
    v_buffer_size binary_integer := 48;
    v_buffer_varchar varchar2(48);
    v_buffer_raw raw(48);
    begin
        if p_clob_in is null then
            return null;
        end if;
        dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob, true);
        v_offset := 1;
        for i in 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob_in) / v_buffer_size) loop
            dbms_lob.read(p_clob_in, v_buffer_size, v_offset, v_buffer_varchar);
            v_buffer_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_buffer_varchar);
            v_buffer_raw := utl_encode.base64_decode(v_buffer_raw);
            dbms_lob.writeappend(v_blob, utl_raw.length(v_buffer_raw), v_buffer_raw);
            v_offset := v_offset + v_buffer_size;
        end loop;
        v_result := v_blob;
        dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob);
        return v_result;
end decode_base64;
```

Comment: Are you sure you use "the same" Base64 representation on both ends (padding in particular)?

Comment: The problem seems to come from the decoding part in PL/SQL. Can you share those? (also is there a particular reason why you would not use binary data transfer and BLOBs?)

Comment: @fge - we've tried to check that; I know commons in Java is using 76 as chunk size, while in PL/SQL we're using 48. As far as I know that shouldn't make a difference, right?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat, I added the code I'm using in both Java and PL/SQL. As for the binary data transfer - there's a sort of company rule that we should encode it to keep it 'safe'. When not encoding-decoding during transfer and just sending plain bytes, it works, but "that's not good enough".

Comment: How are you sending the file from Java to PL/SQL?

Comment: @mttdbrd, the Java code is a RESTful webservice using Jersey. So PL/SQL is invoking the webservice (GET), and it gets an XML back. In that XML there is a tag `<annex><filename>...</filename><binaryContent>BASE64-encoded-string</binaryContent></annex>`

Comment: And you've verified that the string inside that XML matches byte for byte what Java outputs?

Comment: Yes, we did. The output that gets to PL/SQL in the code is exactly the same as what I'm sending from Java.

Comment: Your PL/SQL program looks like the encoding part (blob -> character file), not the decoding part (character file -> blob).

Comment: You're totally right. I'll check for the decoding part and post that.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat there you go, I added the decode part as well. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: If you compare the Base64 encode on the PL/SQL side to the Base64 encode on the Java side, do they match?

Comment: @mttdbrd this gets even weirder! So I save (from Java) the file when I receive it (the Base64-string) - corrupt, of course. I save it after I decoded it - works. (...) I get it back, save it before I encode it, works. I encode it, save it once again (so the Base64 String), corrupt (as expected). I send that file to PL/SQL. So theoretically speaking, the file I receive (Base64-String) & the file I send (Base64-String) should be exactly the same. I opened both PDF's in Notepad++ and used the compare-plugin - THEY ARE EXACTLY THE SAME. So I guess it's the PL/SQL-decode side that doesn't work?

Comment: We just checked: the Base64-String I receive in Java (from PL/SQL) is exactly - to the byte - the same as the Base64-String I send from Java (to PL/SQL), which is also exactly the same as the Base64-String PL/SQL receives from Java (which rules out problems in Java and in the communication layer). Which leads me to the question: how come that, when I upload a BLOB, encode it in PL/SQL, decode it in PL/SQL, then download it - why does it work? As when I have a BLOB, encode it in PL/SQL, send it to Java, receive the same encoded CLOB back, decode it, it doesn't work?

Comment: I built a small test case and your encode/decode functions return the original on all cases I've tested.

Comment: Most of this kind of problems come from small things... So what happened? I'm sending the Base64-String back inside an XML. In PL/SQL we extract that String into a clob before we decode it back to a blob. We printed and checked that String... it was correct. When we tried to check the difference between the clob we send from PL/SQL with the clob we get back in PL/SQL, we found some char(10) & char(13) - linebreaks, essentially. Not visible for the eye, but making the clob (and decoded blob) corrupt. A translate function got those out and now it works as a charm.

Comment: @testuser Congrats. That's a ball buster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this kind of problems come from small things...

So what happened? I'm sending the Base64-String back inside an XML. In PL/SQL we extract that String into a clob before we decode it back to a blob.

We printed and checked that String... it was correct.

When we tried to check the difference between the clob we send from PL/SQL with the clob we get back in PL/SQL, we found some char(10) & char(13) - linebreaks, essentially. Not visible for the eye, but making the clob (and decoded blob) corrupt. A translate function got those out and now it works as a charm.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: So you get the base64 string inside XML then extract it to a CLOB. Can you do the extract directly into a BLOB? I suspect that the CLOB may be "helpfully" converting what it considers to be line-ending characters from Unix to DOS styles, or vice versa. Just a thought. Share and enjoy.

Comment: The problem is we need the CLOB right after extracting it from the XML, to be able to Base64-decode it (back to a BLOB). The decode function assumes the IN-parameter to be a CLOB, and the OUT-parameters to be a BLOB. So it seems to me that would be a work-around (I admit, the translation now also is a work-around)

Comment: Provide an example ?